# WPF MVVM Сохранить изменения DataGrid в базу данных

Tags: база-данных, mvvm, entity-framework-core, datagrid

всем. Подскажите пожалуйста как мне сохранить изменения, которые происходят в DataGrid, в базу данных. Использую EF. ПО подходу у меня DataBaseFirst. Так же я изучаю еще mvvm, поэтому если будет возможность распишите поподробнее. Для отображения в DataGrid я использую ObservableCollection<>, я так же понимаю что нужно подписаться на событие CollectionChanged. Но не понимаю как это сделать. Model, ViewModel, View прикладываю.

Model: InfoDrill

```
public partial class InfoDrill
{
    public int Uid { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// № скважины
    /// </summary>
    public string? HoleId { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Тип выработки
    /// </summary>
    public int? TypeLcode { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Название участка
    /// </summary>
    public int? PlaceSite { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Номер ПЛ
    /// </summary>
    public double? Profile { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Долгота
    /// </summary>
    public double? Easting { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Широта
    /// </summary>
    public double? Northing { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Абс. отм.
    /// </summary>
    public double? Elevation { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Диаметр бурения, мм
    /// </summary>
    public double? Diam { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Азимут ист., °
    /// </summary>
    public double? Azimuth { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Угол наклона от горизонта, °
    /// </summary>
    public double? Dip { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Глубина скважины,м
    /// </summary>
    public double? Depth { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Уровень ПВ, м
    /// </summary>
    public double? Uroven { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Абс. отм. уровня, м
    /// 
    /// </summary>
    public double? UrAbs { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Начало бурения
    /// </summary>
    public DateOnly? StartDate { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Окончание бурения
    /// </summary>
    public DateOnly? EndDate { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Геолог
    /// </summary>
    public int? Geolog { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Примечания
    /// </summary>
    public string? NotesCommentsText { get; set; }

    public int Project { get; set; }

    public virtual Person? GeologNavigation { get; set; }

    public virtual Place? PlaceSiteNavigation { get; set; }

    public virtual Project ProjectNavigation { get; set; } = null!;

    public virtual ICollection<Rock> Rocks { get; set; } = new List<Rock>();

    public virtual Mine? TypeLcodeNavigation { get; set; }
}
```

Данный класс мне создался автоматом, когда подключался к БД PostgreSQL

ViewModel

```
internal class Info_DrilModel : ViewModelBase
    {
        private NavigationManager navigationManager;
        private AnzasContext dbcontext;


        private ObservableCollection<InfoDrill> _infodrill;
        /// <summary>
        /// Информаиция по скважинам
        /// </summary>
        public ObservableCollection<InfoDrill> InfoDrills
        {
            set => Set(ref _infodrill, value);
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Выбранный элемент скважин
        /// </summary>
        private InfoDrill? _selectedInfodril;
        public InfoDrill? Selected_InfoDrill
        {
            get => _selectedInfodril;
            set => Set(ref _selectedInfodril, value);
        }
 public Info_DrilModel(NavigationManager navigationManager, AnzasContext db)
        {
            this.navigationManager = navigationManager;
            this.dbcontext = db;
        
            InfoDrills = new ObservableCollection<InfoDrill>();
           
            InfoDrills = dbcontext.InfoDrills
                .Include(p => p.PlaceSiteNavigation)
                .Include(item => item.TypeLcodeNavigation)
                .Include(item => item.GeologNavigation)
                .AsNoTracking().ToObservableCollection();

           
           
        }
}
```

View

```
 <DataGrid Margin="20"
                          ItemsSource="{Binding InfoDrills , Mode=OneWay }"
                         
                          AutoGenerateColumns="False"
                          CanUserReorderColumns="True"
                          IsReadOnly="{Binding IsReadOnlyData}">

                 
                    <DataGrid.Columns>
                        <DataGridTextColumn Header="№ скважины"
                                            Binding="{Binding HoleId}"
                                            MinWidth="120"
                                            Width="20"
                                            CellStyle="{StaticResource CenterGridCell}"
                                            Visibility="{Binding Source={x:Reference HoleIdCheked},
                                                                    Path=IsChecked, 
                                                                    Converter={StaticResource BooleanToVisibilityConverter}}" />
                        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Тип выработки"
                                            Binding="{Binding TypeLcodeNavigation.TypeLcode }"
                                            MinWidth="180"
                                            Width="*"
                                            CellStyle="{StaticResource CenterGridCell}"
                                            Visibility="{Binding Source={x:Reference TypeLcodeCheked},
                                                                    Path=IsChecked, 
                                                                    Converter={StaticResource BooleanToVisibilityConverter}}" />
                        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Название участка"
                                            Binding="{Binding PlaceSiteNavigation.NamePlaceSite}"
                                            MinWidth="160"
                                            Width="*"
                                            CellStyle="{StaticResource CenterGridCell}"
                                            Visibility="{Binding Source={x:Reference PlaceSiteCheked},
                                                                    Path=IsChecked, 
                                                                    Converter={StaticResource BooleanToVisibilityConverter}}" />
                        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Номер ПЛ"
                                            Binding="{Binding Profile}"
                                            MinWidth="120"
                                            Width="*"
                                            CellStyle="{StaticResource CenterGridCell}"
                                            Visibility="{Binding Source={x:Reference ProfileCheked},
                                                                    Path=IsChecked, 
                                                                    Converter={StaticResource BooleanToVisibilityConverter}}" />
                        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Долгота"
                                            Binding="{Binding Easting}"
                                            MinWidth="120"
                                            Width="*"
                                            CellStyle="{StaticResource CenterGridCell}"
                                            Visibility="{Binding Source={x:Reference EastingCheked},
                                                                    Path=IsChecked, 
                                                                    Converter={StaticResource BooleanToVisibilityConverter}}" />
                        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Широта"
                                            Binding="{Binding Northing}"
                                            MinWidth="120"
                                            Width="*"
                                            CellStyle="{StaticResource CenterGridCell}"
                                            Visibility="{Binding Source={x:Reference NorthingCheked},
                                                                    Path=IsChecked, 
                                                                    Converter={StaticResource BooleanToVisibilityConverter}}" />
                        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Абс. отм."
                                            Binding="{Binding Elevation}"
                                            MinWidth="120"
                                            Width="*"
                                            CellStyle="{StaticResource CenterGridCell}"
                                            Visibility="{Binding Source={x:Reference ElevationCheked},
                                                                    Path=IsChecked, 
                                                                    Converter={StaticResource BooleanToVisibilityConverter}}" />
                        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Диаметр бурения,мм"
                                            Binding="{Binding Diam}"
                                            MinWidth="180"
                                            Width="*"
                                            CellStyle="{StaticResource CenterGridCell}"
                                            Visibility="{Binding Source={x:Reference DiamCheked},
                                                                    Path=IsChecked, 
                                                                    Converter={StaticResource BooleanToVisibilityConverter}}" />
                        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Азимут ист.°"
                                            Binding="{Binding Azimuth}"
                                            MinWidth="160"
                                            Width="*"
                                            CellStyle="{StaticResource CenterGridCell}"
                                            Visibility="{Binding Source={x:Reference AzimuthCheked},
                                                                    Path=IsChecked, 
                                                                    Converter={StaticResource BooleanToVisibilityConverter}}" />
                        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Угол наклона от горизонта,°"
                                            Binding="{Binding Dip}"
                                            MinWidth="220"
                                            Width="*"
                                            CellStyle="{StaticResource CenterGridCell}"
                                            Visibility="{Binding Source={x:Reference DipCheked},
                                                                    Path=IsChecked, 
                                                                    Converter={StaticResource BooleanToVisibilityConverter}}" />
                        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Глубина скважины,м"
                                            Binding="{Binding Depth}"
                                            MinWidth="180"
                                            Width="*"
                                            CellStyle="{StaticResource CenterGridCell}"
                                            Visibility="{Binding Source={x:Reference DepthCheked},
                                                                    Path=IsChecked, 
                                                                    Converter={StaticResource BooleanToVisibilityConverter}}" />
                        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Уровень ПВ, м"
                                            Binding="{Binding Uroven}"
                                            MinWidth="140"
                                            Width="*"
                                            CellStyle="{StaticResource CenterGridCell}"
                                            Visibility="{Binding Source={x:Reference UrovenCheked},
                                                                    Path=IsChecked, 
                                                                    Converter={StaticResource BooleanToVisibilityConverter}}" />
                        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Абс. отм. уровня, м"
                                            Binding="{Binding UrAbs}"
                                            MinWidth="160"
                                            Width="*"
                                            CellStyle="{StaticResource CenterGridCell}"
                                            Visibility="{Binding Source={x:Reference UrAbsCheked},
                                                                    Path=IsChecked, 
                                                                    Converter={StaticResource BooleanToVisibilityConverter}}" />
                        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Начало бурения"
                                            Binding="{Binding StartDate}"
                                            MinWidth="140"
                                            Width="*"
                                            CellStyle="{StaticResource CenterGridCell}"
                                            Visibility="{Binding Source={x:Reference StartDateCheked},
                                                                    Path=IsChecked, 
                                                                    Converter={StaticResource BooleanToVisibilityConverter}}" />
                        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Окончание бурения"
                                            Binding="{Binding EndDate}"
                                            MinWidth="160"
                                            Width="*"
                                            CellStyle="{StaticResource CenterGridCell}"
                                            Visibility="{Binding Source={x:Reference EndDateCheked},
                                                                    Path=IsChecked, 
                                                                    Converter={StaticResource BooleanToVisibilityConverter}}" />
                        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Геолог"
                                            Binding="{Binding GeologNavigation.Surname }"
                                            MinWidth="120"
                                            Width="*"
                                            CellStyle="{StaticResource CenterGridCell}"
                                            Visibility="{Binding Source={x:Reference GeologCheked},
                                                                    Path=IsChecked, 
                                                                    Converter={StaticResource BooleanToVisibilityConverter}}" />
                        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Примечания"
                                            Binding="{Binding NotesCommentsText}"
                                            MinWidth="120"
                                            Width="*"
                                            CellStyle="{StaticResource CenterGridCell}"
                                            Visibility="{Binding Source={x:Reference NotesCheked},
                                                                    Path=IsChecked, 
                                                                    Converter={StaticResource BooleanToVisibilityConverter}}" />



                    </DataGrid.Columns>
```

ViewModelBase

```
internal abstract class ViewModelBase : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler? PropertyChanged;

        protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string? PropertyName = null)
        {
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(PropertyName));
        }

        protected virtual bool Set<T>(ref T field, T value, [CallerMemberName] string? PropertyName = null)
        {
            // Если значение поля которое хотим обновить уже соответсвует тому значение которое мы передали возвращаем ложь
            if (Equals(field, value)) return false;
            field = value;
            OnPropertyChanged(PropertyName);
            return true;
        }
    }
```